# Unexpected end of file looking for </head> tag in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, master-pages, html5boilerplate

1. in master page I'm getting error  saying - "Unexpected end of file
   looking for `</head>` tag
2. can you show me where i did mistake with head tag ?

my design code of master page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">

<title>Megashop</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>        
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/common.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/ddsmoothmenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.elastislide.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.accordion.js"></script>
<script src="js/light_box.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () { $(".inline").colorbox({ inline: true, width: "50%" }); });</script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/orange.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Are you using a CMS? Wich one?

Comment: Try and remove all elements (leaving the `<head>` tag to see if the error is still there. After that try and add one at a time the tags to see which is causing the error. Also, which version of visual studio do you have?

Comment: The error has something to do with the elements inside `ContentPlaceHolder2`.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error comeup when you use [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). To fix it, look in your ASPX file for all comments, where you might have mentioned `<head>` (such as below) and remove them

```
<!-- add xyz functionality in <head> tag -->
```

Answer (score 1):

this problem is for when a head tag exist in your comments.
example:

```
<!-- add to the <head> of your page -->
```

you should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If the comments include at least one "", you will receive that error.

Replacing that with simply "head" or entirely deleting the comment will resolve the issue.

Have a nice day!